# Filter an object based on data in angular js

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, json

I have a data object like this :

```
$scope.data =  [
      {
        "name": "1001",
        "queue": [
          {
            "number": "111",
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "name": "1002",
        "queue": [

        ]
      },
      {
        "name": "1008",
        "queue": [
          {
            "number": "222",
          }
        ]
      }]
```

I'm using angular js.
I have first declared 3 arrays:

```
$scope.a = [];
$scope.b = [];
$scope.c = [];
```

The desired output that I want :

If I do `console.log($scope.a);` then the output should be :

```
{
    "name": "1001",
    "queue": [
      {
        "number": "111",
      }
    ]
  }
```

If I do `console.log($scope.b);` then the output should be :

```
{
    "name": "1008",
    "queue": [
      {
        "number": "222",
      }
    ]
  }
```

If I do `console.log($scope.c);` then the output should be :

```
{
    "name": "1002",
    "queue": [

    ]
  }
```

I want to go through the data and push the objects where the queue number is `111` into `$scope.a`, push the objects where the queue number is `222` into `$scope.b` and push the objects where the queue array is empty into `$scope.c`. I'm not able to figure how to filter this object by checking the values from the queue array. How do I do it in AngularJS?

Comment: Please update the question with output.

Comment: There's no output. I want to filter the data based on the queue number and store it into the different arrays accordingly

Comment: Please add the sample output for the above input.

Comment: As per the JSON in your question, can you show what is needed inside `$scope.a`, `$scope.b` and `$scope.c`?

Comment: check the updated question for the desired output

Comment: Now it's clear. Previously it had queue numbers like 122.. will look into it..

Comment: yea sorry for that typing mistake

Comment: This seems like a really odd, specific, and fragile requirement.  Why do you need to present the data on the front end in such a radically different format from what the server is delivering?  This kind of transformation will make it very difficult to keep the server and client data in sync....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is quite simple to solve this problem @Navin. Just loop through the array of objects checking the queue number within each object. As and when you encounter a right match, insert into the corresponding array.

I have attached the working snippet below.

```js
var data = [{
    "name": "1001",
    "queue": [{
      "number": "111",
    }]
  },
  {
    "name": "1002",
    "queue": [

    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "1008",
    "queue": [{
      "number": "222",
    }]
  }
];
var a = [];
var b = [];
var c = [];
for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  if (data[i].queue.length != 0) {
    for (j = 0; j < data[i].queue.length; j++) {
      if (data[i].queue[j].number == 111) {

        a.push(data[i]);
      } else if (data[i].queue[j].number == 222) {
        b.push(data[i]);
      }
    }
  } else {
    c.push(data[i]);
  }
}
a = JSON.stringify(a);
b = JSON.stringify(b);
c = JSON.stringify(c);
console.log(a + "\n" + b + "\n" + c);
```

Comment: can you help me with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53700568/angularjs-custom-filter-to-check-for-values-inside-a-data-array)

Answer (score 0):

do it through a for loop , as `$scope.data` is an object array
for eg.

```
for(i=0;i<=$scope.data.length ;i++){
   if($scope.data[i].queue.length != 0){
       for(j=0;j<=$scope.data[i].queue.length;j++){
         if($scope.data[i].queue[j].number == 111){
               $scope.a.push =$scope.data[i]
           }else if($scope.data[i].queue[j].number == 222){
                      $scope.b.push =$scope.data[i]    
                   }
        }
    }else{
             $scope.c.push = $scope.data[i]
           }
 }
```

I hope this may help you.

Comment: Hey Anny, you've got the logic correct here in your answer. But there's a mistake in how you `push` the data into the array. The correct way to push is by placing the part that is to be pushed inside parenthesis `()`. Check my answer. Your logic is right though.